# Get CSS-selector or XPath based on textContent

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrapy

As far as I know, Python libraries, such as BeautifulSoup or scrapy can return a text content for a provided CSS-selector or XPath. 
What I'm looking for is the opposite - I want to provide a text that needs to be scraped and want to get CSS-selector or XPath for getting that text.

Is this something, that can be done with the existing library?

```py
html = """
<h1 class="some-class">Article title</h1>
<div class="article-text">
  <p class="article-paragraph">Article paragraph text 1.</p>
  <p class="article-paragraph">Article paragraph text 2.</p>
</div>
"""

# ... some magic here with get_selector_by_text_content()
article_title_selector = get_selector_by_text_content("Article title", html) # 'h1.some-class'
article_body_selector = get_selector_by_text_content("Article paragraph text 1. \nArticle paragraph text 2.", html) # 'div.article-text > p'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use lxml, you can get the xpath of your supplied texts:

```
import lxml.html
from lxml import etree

targets = ['Article title','Article paragraph text 1.','Article paragraph text 2.']

root = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
tree = etree.ElementTree(root)
for e in root.iter():
    for target in targets:
        if e.text== target:
            print(tree.getpath(e))
```

Output:

```
/div/h1
/div/div/p[1]
/div/div/p[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It would just be `//*[contains(text(),'Text')]` or `:contains("Text")` (with cssselect)